# Determine if value is already selected in another select field

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following select box:

```
<select class="event_selection" name="Event[]" id="Event_<?php echo $i; ?>" > 
    <option value="original">Select Event...</option> 
    <option value="1">One</option> 
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I have a couple of these on my form. When a user selects a value from the drop down I'd like to make sure that the value isn't already selected on another select that has the same class.

Is there an easy way to do this? If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Register a `changed` event on the select tags, when one option is selected, remove it from the other drop downs. Restore previously removed options if needed. The `disabled` attribute should work nicely.

Comment: "*When a user selects a value from the drop down I'd like to make sure that the value isn't already selected on another select that has the same class.*". And what if it is?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas If it is already selected, I'd like to just write a little warning to a div saying that they already selected that value on a previous select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it so that you cannot select any value twice:

```
var $coll = $( '.event_selection' ).on( 'change', function () {
    $coll.children().prop( 'disabled', false );
    $coll.each(function () {
        var val = this.value;
        if ( val === 'original' ) return;
        $coll.not( this ).children( '[value="' + val + '"]' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QVbQ6/2/

---

```
var $coll = $( '.event_selection' );

$( '#timeline_table' ).on( 'change', '.event_selection', function () {

    // my code
    $coll.children().prop( 'disabled', false );
    $coll.each(function () {
        var val = this.value;
        if ( val === 'original' ) return;
        $coll.not( this ).children( '[value="' + val + '"]' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
    });

    // your other code...

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution. I already have a function for this and I'm not sure how to incorporate your solution in my existing function. How could I update my current function to do this? I'm using jQuery instead of $ because I'm using wordpress (just an FYI). I created a JS fiddle that already has my initial solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VxgmB/1/

Comment: @user1048676 Btw, you don't have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Just pass the `$` variable in your ready handler: `jQuery(function ( $ ) { your_code; });`

Comment: @user1048676 First save the jQuery object that contains all those SELECT boxes into a variable: `var $coll = $( '.event_selection' );`. Once you do that, you can pretty much copy-paste the function body from my answer into your "change" handler (at the beginning, for instance).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've updated my JS fiddle to try and reflect what you did with your example above and it still doesn't work. Here is my new JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VxgmB/4/

Comment: @user1048676 That demo doesn't work because your jQuery code delegates the "change" event to a "#timeline_table" element, but in the HTML code of the demo, there is no such element. **Proper demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VxgmB/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("select.event_selection").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == $("select.event_selection").not(this).val()) {
        // match found
        alert('You have already selected this value');
        $(this).val('original'); //sets this back to original        
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks but it isn't for every select that I want to compare. I'd only like to compare to see if it was already selected in a previous select that has a class of event_selection

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".event_selection").change(function(){
 if($(".event_selection:selected[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").length > 1) {
  // there are more than one select with this class and same value, do whatever you need
 }
});
```